# "Race" of the primes modulo $1,3,7,9\ \pmod {10}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The "race" starts with the prime $11$. The number of primes $1, 3, 7, 9 \pmod {10}$ is denoted after every occurring prime.

> Does the lead change infinitely often?
>
> And does every "runner" have the lead infinitely many often?

Note that a "runner" has the lead only if it is ahead of all the other "runners".

I simulated the situation up to the prime $100\ 000\ 007$.

The last time the primes with residue $1, 3, 7, 9$ regained the lead was at the prime $52\ 491\ 031$, $99\ 712\ 103$,$99\ 712\ 177$ and $6\ 445\ 919$.

> Additional question. If the digits were drawn randomly, would every digit
>   have the lead infinitely often?

Comment: Perhaps, someone checks my results...

Comment: see page 17  http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf

Comment: Upto $10^9$, the prime $52\ 491\ 031$ remains ($1$ did not regain the lead) , at $325\ 710\ 479$ , $9$ regained the lead, at $997\ 519\ 823$, $3$ regained the lead and at $997\ 519\ 717$, $7$ regained the lead. It seems $1$ and $9$ have the lead quite rare, which is also the observation made in Will's link.

Comment: 1 gets the lead at 5,181,718,441 and trades it with 7 for a while, then back to the usual 3/7 tradeoff.  9 and 7 start at 13,681,963,949 until it's back to 3/7 at 16,.. for a while then 9/3 for a bit.  Looking farther, while most of the time it seems to be 3/7,  9 has the lead at 48,443,309,899, and 1 has the lead at 77,240,695,541.  They appear later as well (9 at 241,702,195,529 for example and 1 at 597,254,187,011).

Comment: If you care about larger examples, 1 has the lead at 9,004,483,237,131.  9 has the lead at 5,219,070,885,209.  3 and 7 still are more commonly found in the lead.